# java security error when loading dll from a Javascript call but not when directly called from applet

Tags: java, javascript, security

I have an applet the `loadslibrary` using a `System` call through a static method called `loadLibrary`.

```
System.loadLibrary("ReadRegistry");
```

This works fine as long as I call `loadLibrary` from within the applet. However, if from javascript I access another method, called `handleLoad()`, which calls the `loadLibrary` method, I get a java security error when I try to call the `System.loadLibrary` statement.

Why would that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a call is invoked by JS, a JRE becomes less trusting of it.

To solve that, wrap the problem code in a [`PrivilegedAction`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/PrivilegedAction.html) and call it using one of the [`AccessController.doPriviliged()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#method_summary) variants.